# After deploying wordpress project to server not loading wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment

I am working on a WordPress project, the job is to deploy everything from the old server to the new server.

So I downloaded everything from the old server.

I deployed a WordPress project to paid hosting, I deployed manually by pushing all the `public_html` folder to the server.

First, without a `database` connection, it was showing me a database connection error but after the database connection, it is showing me a hosting page instead of my WordPress project page.

How can I fix it and is there a configuration that needs to be fixed?
Kindly guide me and help me in this matter.
Also is it a domain configuration issue?
The domain is configuration is on the old server and I didn't set it up for the new server yet.

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem, I needed to lunch two websites on one server and I face the "apache function page".  It is due to the apache setting or cookies, ask your service provider to fix it.

Comment: I hosted on A2hosting and they share the link to test the site but when I complete the whole deployment I can't access the site either the wp-admin.
Someone told me to check the wp-options but it doesn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues yesteday when i tried to move my woocommerce exercise from localhost to my domain(live hosting),broken all links,images,routes etc ...There is no way to fix all that whithout paid plugins, maybe someone can go through whole db and change URL-s,i cant,and after that, the question remains whether I have problems elsewhere in the local WP code,who know where in code i also have embed "localhost" URL.
I cant give you solution but i must share my frustration with this tehnology which doesnt allow normall development process like 1)development -> 2)testing -> 3)deployment .